# Assigning a matrix as an element of another matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the `n x m` matrices `A,B,C`. I want  to make a "3 x 1" block-matrix `Y`, such that

`Y(1,1) = A, Y(2,1) = B, Y(3,1) = C`. Is that possible in `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is available using `cell arrays`.

if you have as stated three matrices `A`,`B`,`C` of size `n x m`.

to assign them to Y your code should be.

```
Y{1,1} = A;
Y{2,1} = B;
Y{3,1} = C;
```

As you see cell arrays use `{}` instead of `()`.
For more information about `cell arrays` visit [Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to storing the three `n x m` matrices in a cell vector, consider storing them in a three-dimensional array of size `n x m x 3`. You can use the [cat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html?refresh=true) command to concatenate the matrices along the third dimension, for example:

```
>> n = 2; m = 3;
>> A = rand(n, m); B = rand(n, m); C = rand(n, m);
>> Y = cat(3, A, B, C)

Y(:,:,1) =

         0.792207329559554         0.655740699156587         0.849129305868777
         0.959492426392903        0.0357116785741896         0.933993247757551


Y(:,:,2) =

         0.678735154857773         0.743132468124916         0.655477890177557
         0.757740130578333         0.392227019534168         0.171186687811562


Y(:,:,3) =

         0.706046088019609          0.27692298496089        0.0971317812358475
        0.0318328463774207        0.0461713906311539         0.823457828327293
```

This can also be accomplished by [indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html), for example:

```
>> Y(:,:,1) = A; Y(:,:,2) = B; Y(:,:,3) = C;
>> Y

Y(:,:,1) =

         0.792207329559554         0.655740699156587         0.849129305868777
         0.959492426392903        0.0357116785741896         0.933993247757551


Y(:,:,2) =

         0.678735154857773         0.743132468124916         0.655477890177557
         0.757740130578333         0.392227019534168         0.171186687811562


Y(:,:,3) =

         0.706046088019609          0.27692298496089        0.0971317812358475
        0.0318328463774207        0.0461713906311539         0.823457828327293
```